# System.BadImageFormatException occured while calling MWArray in my C# project

Tags: c#, matlab, badimageformatexception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MWArray, Version=2.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db86f' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This error can come from two sources:

1-Corrupted file, the dll you are triyng to load has been damaged

2-You are triyng to load an x64 assembly in an x86 process

Usually the most typical error is (2), try to change your project to x64 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "run time include in package" in later versions of Matlab.
In earlier versions, it's called "add MCR".
It makes an installation file which can hold dependencies all together.